# OnMouseLeave Event only firing after the mouse pointer leaves parent element

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent

I have a div element with `OnMouseEnter()` that changes its class and a `OnMouseLeave()` that reverts its class, the `onMouseLeave()`  only works after the mouse pointer leaves the parent div of the element.

Working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/old-violet-7ipbvb?file=/src/Grid.jsx&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

More details - Basically I have a parent div (called canvas) that has child divs (cells) inside to represent a matrix, the child divs change color on mouse enter and revert to original color on mouseleave, the problem is that cells change color on mouse enter but only revert the color when the pointer leave their parent div.

```
 const [canvas, setcanvas] = useState([[]]);
 const handleenter1 = (row, col) => {
       const a = []
       for (var i = 0; i<50; i++){
        a.push([]);
         for (var j=0; j<20; j++){
           if (i=== row && j === col){
              var obj = {x: i, y: j,  status: "wall"};
              a[i].push(obj);
           }
           else {
               obj = canvas[i][j];
              a[i].push(obj);
           }
       
        }
     }
     setcanvas(a);  
}
const handleleave1 = (row, col ) => {}
const create =  () => {
    let a = [];
 for (var i = 0; i<50; i++){
    a.push([]);
     for (var j=0; j<20; j++){
      if (i === 10 && j === 10){
         var obj = {x: i, y: j,  status: "starter"};
        a[i].push(obj);
      }
      else {
          obj = {x: i, y: j, status: "space"};
        a[i].push(obj);
      }
        
    }
 }
 setcanvas(a);

 }
 useEffect(create, []);
 
    
    const m = canvas.map((objlist,index1)=> {
        return (objlist.map((obj,index) => {
         
            return (
            <div key = {`${index1} ${index}`} 
                 onMouseEnter ={()=> {handleenter1(obj.x,obj.y)}}
                 onMouseLeave = {()=> { handleleave1(obj.x ,obj.y) }}>
            </div>);
        }));
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a race-condition between your `handleentter1` and `handleleave1` functions where mouseleave does not see the updated `canvas` in time, which is why it mistakenly keeps the previous cell black.

If you refactor the functions to imperatively update the canvas state's status for the known row/column, you won't run into this issue. Now the `setcanvas` does not collide since it's just setting the one cell it cares about and not all the other cells.

Here's a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-goldberg-8cv0xu?file=/src/Grid.jsx:113-412):

```
const handleenter1 = (row, col) => {
  setcanvas((c) => {
    const p = [...c];
    p[row][col].status = "wall";
    return p;
  });
};

const handleleave1 = (row, col) => {
  setcanvas((c) => {
    const p = [...c];
    p[row][col].status = "space";
    return p;
  });
};
```